# Is it possible to pass a method to a Criteria restriction?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I got a trouble using Hibernate Criteria restriction. I'll give you a example of what I need to do. It's something like that:

I got a class named CandyStore. My CandyStore got a List of saleable candies.

```
public class CandyStore {
    private String name;
    private List<Candy> candies;

    public Candy getBestCandy() {
    // there is something here
    }
}

public class Candy implements Saleable {
    private Flavour flavour;

    public Flavour getFlavour() {
        return this.flavour;
    }
}
```

I have a lot of candy stores on my DB. So my problem is:
I want to find a candy store in DB by name and the best candy' flavour can't be NULL. I don't want to duplicate the getBestCandy() logic, because it's mutable. I want to use the method logic inside the criteria. Is it possible? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have a function passed to a criteria. The best way would be to have a separate table **Best_Candies** with columns **candy_store_id, candy_id** and store the best candies in it.